# Make directory appear as other directory - mount trickery?

Tags: linux, mount, chroot

we operate within a corporate environment with many slightly weird constraints, to become effective in this environment we have created our own system for building and deploying software. The software typically works like this:

1. Download and build and install the software to the temporary location  `$BUILD_ROOT/install`.
2. If all software packages is succesfully installed in step 1, "atomically" copy `$BUILD_ROOT/install` to `$PREFIX` using `rsync`.

This works quite well, but the problem is that some of the files created during the initial install step are not fully relocatable - and will contain contain the path `$BUILD_ROOT/install`.

I wondered if it were possible to make the `$BUILD_ROOT/install` directory (temporarily) appear as `$PREFIX` - i.e. that I could do something like:

1. `mount-trick $PREFIX $BUILD_ROOT/install`
2. configure and install software using `$PREFIX` - but due to the mount-trick the files will actually go to `$BUILD_ROOT/install`.
3. cancel mount-trick
4. `rsync $BUILD_ROOT/install $PREFIX`

I sort of feel something like should be possible using things like bind mount, loop mount and/or chroot?

Comment: I think a better fix would be to store the target path instead of the build path... Is your build system entirely in-house, or is it based on something else? Most build systems can distinguish between build paths and installation paths (*e.g.* autoconf’s `--prefix` and `DESTDIR`).

Comment: This seems to be similar to what the OpenBSD port building system does, using a "fake install directory" before creating the package (which is later installed by `pkg_add`). I don't know much about the internals of that though.

Comment: Our build system is based on whatever native the package uses; i.e. configure+make, cmake, python setup, ... Have not (so far) had 100% succes with DESTDIR

Comment: I’m not saying this means it’s easy, but Linux distributions manage to have 100% success, sometimes with patches admittedly. I *do* think it could be more useful in the long run to spend time getting build/install processes to work, than to spend time on a workaround. Each to his/her own though ;-).